# Concur/Cognos ASCII Character Code Recognition

Tags: cognos, report-studio

I am building a report in Cognos Report Studio which is to be extracted to a CSV format. All is well with the exception of one issue:

One of the fields that is on the report stems from a free form text field in Concur. When this field has line breaks (`ASCII Code: 10`), the CSV recognizes this and breaks my record from 1 row into 2. This break occurs directly on the instance of the line break.

Does Cognos allow for a substitution of character codes? If not, is there another way I can swap the line break for a regular space? I want to substitute the line break for a regular space. In excel this would look something like this:

`=SUBSTITUTE(Field, Chr(10), Chr(32))`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with

`replace([field], char(10), char(32))`